# как выровнять элементы внутри ListView по центру?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выровнять элементы Tag внутри ListView по центру, когда общая ширина этих элементов помещается в экране и не скролится

Этот пример не работает

```dart
Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                height: 50,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: viewNotes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Tag(text: viewNotes[index]['tag']);
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
```